# Where does this proof that $P(\mathbb{N})$ is countable fail?

Tags: real-analysis, natural-numbers

Let $A_k$ be the set of all subsets of $P(\mathbb{N})$ with size $k$.

$A_k\in\mathbb{N}^k$ is countable for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Since $$P(\mathbb{N})=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$$
which is a countable union of countable sets, $P(\mathbb{N})$ must also be countable.

However, $P(\mathbb{N})$ is known to be uncountable. Which step of the proof is wrong?

Comment: The union consists of the empty set, sets containing one element, sets containing two elements, ..., sets containing k elements, etc. where k is a positive integer. None of these is an infinite set, and there are lots of infinite subsets of the natural numbers, for example the set of even natural numbers. If you're still not clear on the problem, then my question to you is which of the sets $A_k$ does the set of all even natural numbers belong to?

Comment: $\mathbb N \notin \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$.

Comment: This reminds me of the fact that sometimes people don't remember that induction fails for "$n=\infty$". Think about it: the sum of the first $N$ natural numbers is some finite positive number, but it is a trivial and very well known fact that the sum of all natural numbers is $-1/12$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This shows that the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable. This does not work for the full powerset. $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ contains infinite subsets, for instance the subset of even integers is not contained in your union but is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2):

Not every subset of $\Bbb{N}$ is finite, so the wrong step is writing the powerset as the union of the collection of all finite sets of size $k ≥ 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(\mathbb{N})=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$$

Is not true, as there are infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ which are not included in the union above. Alternatively, if you interpret that union to include $A_{\infty}=$'the infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$', then that collection is not countable, hence you cannot use "countable union of countable sets is countable" to complete the proof.